# Changing test run results directory in CodedUI or moving results files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I am working with Coded UI Test Projects in Visual Studio 2012 Premium, and running my tests from Test Explorer. I would like to know if there is a form of changing the default directory for the test run files, because `TestRunResultsDirectory` property is readonly. Maybe it would be possible to move my files after executing the whole test?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% on how to change the output directory in VS IDE, but you can do so from the VS Command Prompt with the argument `/resultsfile:[file name]`.  However, this only affects the results that are created when the test is run from the command line, of course.

However, you can find the result files at C:\users[your username]\AppData\Local\Temp\UITestLogs, if you wanted to simply manually move them after the fact.